# JS strange performance behavior: single vs double condition

Tags: javascript

I had this problem to solve on Leetcode:

> Given an array of integers "nums" and an integer "target", return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to "target".
>
> You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.
>
> You can return the answer in any order.
>
> - Example 1:
>
>   Input: nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9
>
>   Output: [0,1]
> - Example 2:
>
>   Input: nums = [3,2,4], target = 6
>
>   Output: [1,2]
> - Example 3:
>
>   Input: nums = [3,3], target = 6
>
>   Output: [0,1]

Then I came up with this solution:

```
const twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    let solution = []

    nums.forEach((number, index) => {
      
      if (solution.length !== 0) {
        return
      }
      
      const remaining = target - number
      
      if (nums.includes(remaining) && (nums.lastIndexOf(remaining) > index)) {
        solution = [index, nums.lastIndexOf(remaining)]
      }
    })
    
    return solution
};
```

and I noticed that the first condition in the if is unnecessary `nums.includes(remaining)`. So I removed it, ending with this code

```
const twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    let solution = []

    nums.forEach((number, index) => {
      
      if (solution.length !== 0) {
        return
      }
      
      const remaining = target - number
      
      if (nums.lastIndexOf(remaining) > index) {
        solution = [index, nums.lastIndexOf(remaining)]
      }
    })
    
    return solution
};
```

Here the strange happens:

- the runtime of the first code is 130/140ms;
- the runtime of the second code (easier in my opinion) is 240/250ms.

Can someone explain the reason of this behavior?

Comment: The first example has the potential to short-circuit on `nums.includes(remaining)` to avoid an unneeded `lastIndexOf` call. The second does not.

Comment: @PCDSandwichMan But `lastIndexOf` has the same complexity as `includes`, and the `lastIndexOf()` test will fail whenever `includes()` would have avoided it.

Comment: It has the same complexity. Not the same implementation. One runs from beginning to end, and the other runs from end to beginning.

Comment: @PCDSandwichMan So what? They both have to scan the entire array to determine that the element isn't found.

Comment: In a worst-case yes but not always. `includes` can break when the `remaining` element is found.

Comment: @PCDSandwichMan And so does `lastIndexOf()`. If the element is at position N, `includes()` read from `0` to `N`, then `lastIndexOf()` read from `length-1` to `N`. If the element doesn't exist, `includes()` has to read the entire array before short-circuiting. So either way, the entire array has to be read.

Comment: But if you only call `lastIndexOf()`, it only has to read from `length-1` to `N` when `remaining` exists.